# What is SphericalPlot3D plotting here?

Tags: plotting

Plot three surfaces with `SphericalPlot3D`:

```
f = {Cos[2 θ] Cos[2 ϕ], Cos[2 θ] Sin[2 ϕ], Sin[2 θ]};
SphericalPlot3D[Evaluate[f], θ, ϕ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I remove the `Evaluate`, by analogy with `Plot` I would expect to get the same three surfaces but all the same color. That's not what I get:

```
SphericalPlot3D[f, θ, ϕ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What's going on here?

Here's a simpler example:

```
f = {1, 0, 0};
SphericalPlot3D[Evaluate[f], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this case, removing the `Evaluate` gives just a line along x:

```
SphericalPlot3D[f, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The three elements of the list are being interpreted as a vector somehow. But I don't know how or why.

Comment: I don't know why removing the `Evaluate` produces that result; however, you can get the expected result with `Show[SphericalPlot3D[#, \[Theta], \[Phi], PlotRange -> 1] & /@ f]`

Comment: SphericalPlot3D has the attribute "HoldAll". This means that f is not evaluated and SphericalPlot3D gets the unevaluated "f". What is astonishing is, that something is plotted at all. Further, if "f" is empty, we get an empty plot. Therefore, although MMA says that SphericalPlot3D has the attribute "HoldAll",  the result is different if "f is an atom or not.

Comment: The same behavior results even when you define `f[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] = ...`, which is also weird.

Comment: @DanielHuber But *all* `Plot` functions have the attribute `HoldAll`. I suspect this really has to do with the fact that under the hood, `SphericalPlot3D` is a special case of `ParametricPlot3D`, and that therefore there's going to be confusion between `{ ... , ... , ...}` as a list of three different functions to plot and `{ ... , ... , ...}` as the coordinate functions of a parameterized surface.

Comment: To eliminate use of the `Evaluate` you could also use `SphericalPlot3D @@ {f, \[Theta], \[Phi]}`; however, that will also produce three colors.